# Package grails 3 plugin as war?

Tags: grails, gradle

I have upgraded our grails 2 application and a plugin to grails 3. The plugin is our REST API and with grails 2 we would package it as a jar (plugin) and war (deployable by itself). With grails 3 I have the plugin working when included in our application but can't figure out how to package it as a war.

First I did a 'grails war' and it says it built to build/libs but it creates a jar and not a war.

Next I added the war plugin to gradle and it fails with "Cannot execute null+null".

Finally I added the grails-web plugin to gradle and it now fails with "Cannot add task ':wp-rest:groovydoc' as a task with that name already exists."

I know with grails 2 that plugins were also applications. Is this still the case with grails 3, and if so, how do I create a war package for the plugin?

Here are my current gradle plugins.

```
apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-plugin-publish"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"

apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
```

Comment: Did you try these solutions: http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/deployment.html ?

Comment: Yes I have tried both "grails package" and "grails war" and both create a jar file. With grails 2 you could do a "grails war" and it would package the plugin into a war that you could deploy standalone. Maybe this isn't possible with grails 3?